# Embedding a referential SVG image into HTML file

Tags: html, css, url, svg, background-image

I have a project where I want to put simple graphic backgrounds into table cells.  background-image and a small svg file works great!

But I would really like to keep the source all in one file.  That is, I would like to be able to define the image in the HEAD, and refer to it in the inline STYLE css.

I have tried various combinations of ID attributes in the svg and hash references in a css url() function, but no success.  This would seem to be a desirable thing to do, but looking around, I haven't seen a hint of an idea.  Which tells me either it cannot be done, or it is done some other way...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your svg file elsewhere and put that up in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="index.svg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

There might be other methods too..

Best tuts for svg is found [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG).

Answer (score 1):

Actually after asking the question and thinking about it, I realized I had read the answer already.  You need to use a a data url to create an in-line svg graphic.  This you can give to the background-image property of a css class, as thus:

{background-image:url(
"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,\
...\
");}

The encoding utf8 will allow you to type in the code directly, escaping the new lines with backslashes and avoiding double quotes (as far as I know;-).  Now you just set the CLASS of the TD and it works great!

Now all I have to do is figure out how to align the background on the bottom rather than the top...

Comment: Yes, I neglected to format it as code and the line breaks collapsed.

Comment: I have used this technique quite a lot.  Be aware that strictly speaking, the string should be URL-encoded.  I believe IE9 insists on this, making it pretty unreadable.  Firefox and Safari seemed only to object to # (or %23 encoded), and I think they may have gotten past that...

Answer (score 0):

This code might also work:

```
 <svg>
    <use xlink:href="..." /> 
 </svg>
```