# Display inline SVG in multiple locations

Tags: html, svg

Using HTML5, how can you place inline SVG once then display in multiple locations? I want the SVG code to not display where it is placed, but in multiple locations where it is referenced, without relying on CSS. There is a slightly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504085/embedding-a-referential-svg-image-into-html-file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `<use>` tag to display SVG in multiple locations.

```
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <rect id="MyRect" width="60" height="10" fill="blue"/>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <use x="20" y="10" xlink:href="#MyRect" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <use x="20" y="10" xlink:href="#MyRect" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: It is working, but the <svg><defs> block takes a large vertical space on the page even though it doesn't display anything. The <svg><use> blocks also take the same size space no matter how small I make the image. How do I eliminate this padding?

Comment: make the svg containing the <defs> width/height 0